# MVC - Data transformation from one model to another?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller, transformation, ooad, object-oriented-analysis

In the Model View Controller pattern where should data transformation occur?

I have a Model that stores very specific mathematical data. I need to convert that data for a physics simulator(that only accepts data in a certain format) and I'm wondering where the code for that should sit? In general where do you place code that transforms one Model into another type of Model?

Comment: Are you building an enterprise app?

Comment: @BhushanFirake I am integrating two applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like to put this code in the constructor of the derived type of model. In this way, the code that does the conversion is in the class that needs to use it.  I find this way of organizing the code makes it easier to understand, test and maintain.

Using your example, say you have a class as follows (you did not mention what language you were using, so I'll give the code below in C#, but it is very similar in java):

```
public class MathematicalData
{
     //members of class
}
```

Let's say you need to take the members of an instance of MathematicalData and transform them into another class named PhysicsSimulator.  I would require the constructor to PhysicsSimulator to take an instance of MathematicalData as an input parameter, and then populate the members of PhysicsSimulator in this contructor:

```
public class PhysicsSimulator
{
    //constructor
    public PhysicsSimulator(MathematicalData input)
    {
        //put code here to use the members of input to populate members of this instance of PhysicsSimulator
    }
}
```

If the only way you want to create an instace of PhysicsSimulator is by using an instance of MathematicalData, then I would not create a default constructor for PhysicsSimulator.  In this way, the only way to create a PhysicsSimulator would be to pass in a MathematicalData instance.

Comment: Did you intend to say "I would not create a default constructor for PhysicsSimulator" in your last sentence?

Comment: Oops, I accidentally typed the wrong class. Thanks, Dennis, for pointing that out.  I corrected the post.

Comment: I like this suggestion.
Would it be disadvantageous to create a new class called "MathDataBasedPhysicsSimulation" that inherits from PhysicsSimulator and leave the PhySim class as is?

Comment: Sure you could subclass the PhysicsSimulator class if needed.  In the subclass you could also have a constructor that requires a MathematicalData input parameter.  If you want to re-use the code in the PhysicsSimulator base class, you can call the base constructor from the subclass constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you need to design an Adapter interface to achieve this. Making the constructor of the target(`PhysicsSimulator`) accept the source(`MathData`) object would tie them both such that when the source changes for whatever reason the target ***has*** to change.

An adapter will limit the changes to the adapter and will not force the target to change for every change in the source.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I understand. Why would PhysicsSimulator have to change when MathData changes? Because we need to update the constructor? In the other case would we not need to change the Adapter?

Comment: You are right @ArthurWulfWhite the Adapter would have to change. However due to the fact that you are integrating two applications, I am assuming both have their own clients. Changing the constructor of `PhysicsSimulator` just because `MathData` has changed would force all clients of `PhysicsSimulator` to change the way they use it(for no apparent reason from the client perspective).  Since the adapter exposes an _interface_ that `PhysicsSimulator` uses, changes to the Adapter become transparent to the clients of `PhysicsSimulator`. Hope I answered your question.

Comment: I understand now, this is an interesting insight @Sudarshan Shubakar

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical pattern I follow for an MVC web app. Input from the web lands in the Model, and then the **Controller** takes responsibility for transforming the web Model to the Business Tier model before calling the Business Tier action.

To keep the Controller from being bloated with transformation code, I'll offload transformations to [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) whenever it's a fit.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're suggesting in your first paragraph, but AutoMapper is a good suggestion.

Comment: That's not "Web MVC", it's just the Rails-way.